# export the data only in dump file not the table structure in sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am facing issue in exporting the only data in a dump file in oracle.
I am using this query...

```
exp ABPPMGR_OP1/ABPPMGR_OP1_Y2016@i2opqa2 FILE=D:\da_software\software\DA27Sep2016.dmp LOG=D:\da_software\software\DA27Sep2016.log PARFILE=D:\da_software\software\file.par STATISTICS=NONE
```

and in file.par , I provided list of table as this:

```
TABLES=('DEV.MST_ENTERPRISEMASTER,
DEV.MST_TARIFFZONEMASTER,
DEV.MST_INSTANCEMASTER,
DEV.MST_INSTANCEENGINEIDMAP,
DEV.MST_HIERARCHYMASTER,
DEV.MST_ITEMMASTER,
DEV.MST_TRANSAGENTMASTER,
DEV.MST_BODHEADER,
DEV.MST_ITEMGROUPMASTER,
DEV.MST_ORGMASTER,
DEV.MST_SUPCHAINMASTER,
DEV.MST_SITEMASTER,
DEV.MST_PRODUCTMASTER,
DEV.MST_ITEMGROUPDETAIL,
DEV.MST_BUCKETMASTER,
DEV.MST_BOMHEADER,
DEV.MST_BODZONELANEDETAIL,
DEV.MST_PRODHRCYMASTER,
DEV.MST_RESOURCEMASTER,
DEV.MST_ROUTINGHEADER,
DEV.MST_SALESMASTER,
DEV.MST_TRANSSERVICEMASTER,
DEV.MST_PLANMASTER,
DEV.MST_BUCKETDETAIL,
DEV.MST_ITEMSITEMASTER,
DEV.MST_BODDETAIL,
DEV.MST_ITEMBOMROUTING,
DEV.MST_PLANPARAMETERS,
DEV.MST_ROUTINGOPERATION,
DEV.MST_SALESHRCYMASTER,
DEV.MST_SALESPRODDETAIL,
DEV.MST_WORKCENTERMASTER,
DEV.MST_BOMCOMPONENTS,
DEV.MST_WORKCENTERDETAIL,
DEV.MST_OPRESOURCE,
DEV.MST_BOMCOMPONENTSAL,
DEV.MST_CALENDARMASTER,
DEV.MST_CALENDARDETAIL,
DEV.MST_ORGSITERELATION,
DEV.SALESPRODALLOC,
DEV.SALESPRODATP,
DEV.SALESORDERMASTER,
DEV.SALESORDERLINE,
DEV.FORECASTGROUP,
DEV.FORECASTDETAIL,
DEV.SALESORDERLINEPROPERTY,
DEV.SOPROMISE,
DEV.SALESORDERCONSPLAN,
DEV.MST_BUCKETPATTERN,
DEV.MST_OPCALENDAR,
DEV.MST_ITEMSUBMASTER,
DEV.MST_CALBASEDATTR')
```

Please help.

Kind Regards
Rahul

Comment: see this https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g

Comment: Please add a question, include what you already tried and why that didn't work. For example, what was the output of  `exp`? What did you expect? Is there an error while exporting, or while importing?

Comment: @Martin -- The exp statement issued is working. Its exporting the tables but with table structure. I do not want table structure to be copied. I need only data in dump file. Can it be possible to export only data?

Comment: No, that is not possible, a dump file always contains table structure as well. I suspect you are asking this because the table already exists in the target database and you do not want to drop/recreate it. Please look into the `table_exists_action` parameter for imp. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-C9664F8C-19C5-4177-AC20-5682AEABA07F.htm#SUTIL936

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated above,it's not possible to dump just data without a table structure. You can use 'DATA_ONLY=Y' switch while importing, though.

[See DATA_ONLY=Y](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#SUTIL001)

-- Sample statements (you can change to use with .par file)

```
$ exp ABPPMGR_OP1/ABPPMGR_OP1_Y2016@i2opqa2 file=ABPPMGR_OP1.dmp OWNER=ABPPMGR_OP1 LOG=ABPPMGR_OP1_EXP.lst
$ imp file=ABPPMGR_OP1.dmp TABLES=ACTION_CODES, REASON_CODES, WATCH_LISTS, TARGET_WATCH_LISTS, CLEARED_DOCUMENTS DATA_ONLY=Y GRANTS=N  LOG=ABPPMGR_OP1_IMP.lst
```

You should consider using advanced data pump utilities as well.